# TypeError in survival.py module of pymoo

Tags: python, optimization

I'm trying to optimize the variable of one of my objects using pymoo. The setup of the problem is:

```
from pymoo.algorithms.nsga2 import NSGA2
from pymoo.factory import get_sampling, get_crossover, get_mutation, get_termination
from pymoo.model.problem import Problem
from pymoo.visualization.scatter import Scatter


def print_res(res):
    print(res.X)
    print(res.F)

    # Objective Space
    plot = Scatter(title="Objective Space")
    plot.add(res.F, color="red")
    plot.show()


class MyProblem(Problem):
    def __init__(self, calculatorobj, obj1, obj2, obj3, var_no=1, obj_no=1):
        super().__init__(n_var=var_no,
                         n_obj=obj_no,
                         n_constr=0,
                         xl=[0.1, 0.1],
                         xu=[5, 15],
                         elementwise_evaluation=True)
        self.calculatorobj = calculatorobj
        self.obj1 = obj1
        self.obj2 = obj2
        self.obj3 = obj3
        self.algorithm = NSGA2(
            pop_size=2,
            n_offsprings=5,
            sampling=get_sampling("real_random"),
            crossover=get_crossover("real_sbx", prob=0.9, eta=15),
            mutation=get_mutation("real_pm", eta=20),
            eliminate_duplicates=True
        )
        self.termination = get_termination("n_gen", 10)

    def _evaluate(self, x, out, *args, **kwargs):
        calculator = calculatorobj(obj1, obj2, obj3)
        calculator.var1 = x[0] 
        calculator.var2 = x[1]
        f1 = - calculator.var3
        out["F"] = [f1]
```

I'm creating my object within the evaluate class as I'm caching the variables within that class and want it to reset for every iteration, so I'm creating a new object each iteration. I then initialize the problem and try to solve it with minimize:

```
problem = optimize.MyProblem(calculatorobj=calculatorobj, var_no=2, obj_no=1, obj1=obj1,
                              obj2=obj2, obj3=obj3)
res = minimize(problem, problem.algorithm, problem.termination, seed=1, save_history=True, verbose=True)
optimize.print_res(res)
```

But this error comes up:

```
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymoo\optimize.py", line 85, in minimize
    res = algorithm.solve()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymoo\model\algorithm.py", line 227, in solve
    self._solve(self.problem)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymoo\model\algorithm.py", line 322, in _solve
    self.next()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymoo\model\algorithm.py", line 244, in next
    self.initialize()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymoo\model\algorithm.py", line 216, in initialize
    self._initialize()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymoo\algorithms\genetic_algorithm.py", line 85, in _initialize
    pop = self.survival.do(self.problem, pop, len(pop), algorithm=self,
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymoo\model\survival.py", line 91, in do
    feas, infeas = split_by_feasibility(pop, sort_infeasbible_by_cv=True)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymoo\model\survival.py", line 138, in split_by_feasibility
    b = (CV <= 0)
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

I was wondering what 'CV' is? I couldn't find the reference for it in the program so I'm confused as to where it's getting the 'NoneType' from.

Comment: My guess is that it has something to do with how you are "running the module". If this problem involves any code that you wrote yourself, then you should show that code, and also read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and see what you can figure out for yourself. Otherwise, Stack Overflow is not for tech support.

Comment: Hi Karl, thanks for the link. Unfortunately, this is an external module downloaded from the internet, so I am unfamiliar with the internal workings. I'll try and make my question more specific.

Comment: Does this project involve any code that you wrote, or not? If not, then what exactly is your involvement in the process - what steps do you take in order to get to this error message? (Don't answer that here - take it to their tech support.) If so, we can only help you with the code if we actually see the code. But you should first *read the documentation* and try to make sure you understand how to use their library correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CV` stands for constraint violation and is derived from the constraints set to `G` during evaluation.
Does your problem set `n_constr` to a number greater than one, but you in fact to not set any constraints?

@EDIT: I just saw you have updated your question. Not sure what you are trying to do. See the template below for optimization.

(you need to set more than one objective to `out["F"]` to solve a multi-objective problem)

```
from pymoo.algorithms.nsga2 import NSGA2
from pymoo.factory import get_sampling, get_crossover, get_mutation, get_termination
from pymoo.model.problem import Problem
from pymoo.visualization.scatter import Scatter
from pymoo.optimize import minimize



class MyProblem(Problem):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(n_var=2,
                         n_obj=1,
                         n_constr=0,
                         xl=[0.1, 0.1],
                         xu=[5.0, 15.0],
                         elementwise_evaluation=True)

    def _evaluate(self, x, out, *args, **kwargs):

        # add your objective calculation HERE
        out["F"] = x[0] ** 2 + x[1] ** 2


problem = MyProblem()

algorithm = NSGA2(
            pop_size=2,
            n_offsprings=5,
            sampling=get_sampling("real_random"),
            crossover=get_crossover("real_sbx", prob=0.9, eta=15),
            mutation=get_mutation("real_pm", eta=20),
            eliminate_duplicates=True
        )

termination = get_termination("n_gen", 10)


res = minimize(problem, algorithm, termination)

print(res.X)
print(res.F)
```

Comment: Hi Julian, thanks for the helpful explanation! I accidentally set it to 2 beforehand.